# Pound sign displaying as Â£ when generating CSV

Tags: asp.net, encoding, csv

I have a script which loops through a GridView on my web page, and generates a CSV file out of the values.

An issue was reported with this where symbols were being displayed encoded such as:

```
Lorem &amp; Ipsum
&#163;100
```

I've used `Server.HtmlDecode()`, and this has fixed the decoded the values, fixing the ampersand, however the pound sign is now displaying a different symbol:

```
Lorem & Ipsum
Â£100
```

Why is this, and how can I fix this so that the `Â` character doesn't appear?

---

The code I'm using to prep the initial value for use in CSV is:

```
Dim Str As String = String.Format("{0}", Server.HtmlDecode(value).Replace(",", "").Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ").Replace(Chr(10), " ").Replace(Chr(13), " "))
```

This decodes the HTML, replaces any commas and line breaks.

Comment: Do your app and the consuming client agree on the encoding? I.e. if your clients open this CSV in, say, Excel - do they chose the same encoding you gave? I remember (german) Excel opening a CSV in ISO-8895-1 as standard, which would show an UTF-8 Pound sign this way.

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue. Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx for how to change it across the app - you can also just change it when you write your CSV out.

Comment: I've checked the CSV file by opening it in notepad, and this displays as £100! No `Â`. What can I do with encoding then to get this to display the same in excel?

Comment: How do you write the CSV out? Is it via Response.Write? If it is, then on the lines before you do the write try Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

Comment: @dash That's right, I use `Response.Write()`. I've just tried putting `Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` before the write, but the character is still displaying when opening in Excel.

Comment: Okay, that means that your source is not UTF encoding and the switch is bothering you. Try System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252) instead (and also look at ISO 8559-1).

Comment: @Dash - That's sorted it! Cheers! Write it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's likely that your source string encoding doesn't match the output encoding. Set the content encoding before you write out the client to avoid a change in encoding that produces the results you've observed.

You can do this by setting Response.ContentEncoding; for example:

```
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
```

Will give you the Windows 1252 code page. You can also use UTF-8 and ISO 8559-1, or, indeed any other encoding you want.

You can also set this consistently across your application by using the [globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx) element in your web.config.